# Facebook App Links With Query Parameters for iOS

Tags: ios, facebook-sdk-4.0

I need to support deep links in my iOS game, with the following format: `myapp://openLevel?levelID=[LEVEL_ID]&timerActive=[TIMER_IS_ACTIVE]` and integrate them with Facebook App Invites.

I already generated a link using the Facebook App Link Generator that matches `myapp://openLevel`. The result was something in this form `https://fb.me/1017800163943870`. Now I'm wondering if creating my App Invite with say for instance `https://fb.me/1017800163943870?levelID=4112&timerActive=YES` as an `appLinkURL` would translate to `myapp://openLevel?levelID=4112&timerActive=YES` as a deep link for my app? If not what is the proper way to create app invites with urls that support query parameters?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You're right, I should've tried it first. I'll share the result soon

Comment: @ceejayoz Well In fact my app is still in development, my app store ID cannot be accessed by facebook until the app gets approved by apple. Before that, it doesn't seem I can test this myself. Still digging though. I'm aware I can use any other approved app's id, but that's not very helpful as I need mine.

Comment: If you have another approved app's ID you should at least be able to `curl -I https://fb.me/<id>?levelID=4112&timerActive=YES` and see if the vars are retained in the redirect.

Comment: @ceejayoz This my very first iOS app, I don't have another approved app.

Comment: Here, this is a facebook generated app link https://fb.me/1017852408271980?levelID=432&timerActive=YES using Electronic Arts' Need for Speed App store ID. using the link on my web browser redirects me to the app store page of the game, not sure how I can go further. The app deep link is supposed to get sent internally to the app - having no access to a random approved app code I don't see how I can test whatsoever. Suggestions?

Comment: You need to modify your URL schemes. There are different questions on this, on how to use Facebook App Links and deep links generally. Try to go into the Info section of your project and creating a new URL Scheme with your app's name, then deeplink using that name, eg appname://whatever

Comment: @ALTN: were you able to test it? I'm facing same issue right now.